Selenium IDE , how to run several project at the same time
I have created 2 Selenium ide projects which have 2 test cases.
Project1 include test1 and test2
Project 2 include test1 and test2
How can I create project 3 that is able to run:
Project 1 and project 2
at the same time.
I can't find any function to do my request.
